# Linking Boost on iOS project. vtable for boost::filesystem::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet

Tags: c++, ios, boost, swiften

I've managed to compile [Swiften](http://swift.im/swiften/) library for a iOS project, but now I'm having linking errors related to [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) library.

I've compiled `Boost` following [these steps](http://freddy.cellcore.org/post/79587278354/boost-c-libraries-on-osx-xcode-5), the error I'm getting during linking is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"vtable for boost::filesystem::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet", referenced from:
  __GLOBAL__I_a in boost(path.o)
NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've read some articles which suggest including some compilation params, but not sure which params or where should I put them. I've also reached [this thread](https://github.com/mz2/boostoniphone/issues/3) with no solution. Anyone else faced this issue? Anyone succeeded compiling and running Swiften for iOS? Any tip on the right direction would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

It seems `filesystem` and `program_options` libs share `utf8_codecvt_facet` object, and one was overriding the other while building `boost`. Finally, I managed to compile the whole `Swiften` library, but when I try to use it I'm getting more linking errors :( I get this error when I declare a `JID` object on my main class:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: 
"Swift::StringPrep::getPrepared(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, 
Swift::StringPrep::Profile)", referenced from:
Swift::JID::nameprepAndSetComponents(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, 
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in JID.o
```

Comment: Are you sure this gist script is building arm64 slices of the boost libraries?

Comment: I had similar linker errors. have you added libc++.dylib to your target? If using latest boost then c++11 compiler might be required. Change build settings c++ language section accordingly.